Binary insertion sort for a list of words
I am doing a enhanced insertion sort which is basically the same as binary insertion sort for a list of words called dictionary but for some reason my list is not getting sorted I cant seem to know the reason why.
I have created 3 functions insert, binary search, and the enhanced insertion sort
    def insert(self, word, position = None):
        if position is None:
            self.words.append(word)
        else:
            self.words.insert(position, word)

    def binarySearch(self, word):
        first = 0
        last = len(self.words)-1
        while first <= last:
            mid = (first + last)//2
            if word == self.words[mid]:
                return mid
            elif word < self.words[mid]:
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                first = mid + 1
        return first

   def enhancedInsertionSort(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self.words)):
            current_value = self.words[i]
            position = self.binarySearch(current_value)
            self.words.insert(current_value, position)
            

I tried using the pop function but I still kept getting errors. Any help would be much appreciated

When you're asking a question about code, the very first tag you add should be for the language that you're using. Please [edit] to add it. Doing so will help get your question in front of the people who are able to answer it.

In addition to the language tag, [edit] your question with a [mcve].  Include what you've learned through your own debugging efforts as well.

There are several issues that cause the malfunctioning of your code:

You have given the arguments to the insert method in the wrong order. Check the documentation

One iteration of your loop only inserts a value, but doesn't remove that value from the position it came from, so this loop will increase the length of the words list, which is not what insertion sort is supposed to do. The size of the list shouldn't change.

insert will shift all values from the given position onwards, but again, that is not what insertion sort is supposed to do. Instead it should only shift the values between the two indices (position and i), and write the value that was at i to index position, so performing a rotation. As you don't want the length of the list to change, insert is not the method you need here. You could use slicing.

For binarySearch to work correctly it must assume that the whole list is sorted, yet you call it at a moment only the partition up to index i is sorted, so this will not always work correctly. You really need a function that only considers the sorted partition for performing a binary search. To make that happen your binarySearch could get an additional parameter which provides the size of the sorted partition.


Here is your code with the corrections to the above points:
    def binarySearch(self, word, length): # Added parameter
        first = 0
        last = length-1 # Use the argument to set the scope of the search
        while first <= last:
            mid = (first + last)//2
            if word == self.words[mid]:
                return mid
            elif word < self.words[mid]:
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                first = mid + 1
        return first

    def enhancedInsertionSort(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self.words)):
            current_value = self.words[i]
            # Indicate the size of the sorted partition:
            position = self.binarySearch(current_value, i)
            # Don't use a method (insert or pop) that changes the size:
            self.words[position+1:i+1] = self.words[position:i]
            self.words[position] = current_value

Other remarks

Python has a native sort method, which is superior to this custom sort implementation.
Python has the bisect library for doing a binary search, which again will outperform your function.
Instead of for i in range(1, len(self.words)) and reading separately self.words[i], use enumerate and islice (to skip the first element)

Taking the last two points into consideration, your code could have this:
import itertools
import bisect

# ...

    def enhancedInsertionSort(self):
        # get value and index in one go using enumerate, and skip first with islice
        for i, current_value in itertools.islice(enumerate(self.words), 1, None):
            # use bisect for binary search
            position = bisect.bisect_left(self.words, current_value, hi=i)
            self.words[position+1:i+1] = self.words[position:i]
            self.words[position] = current_value

